# Fullcalendar week view con angular, sin horas

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

Estoy tratando de crear un calendario como el siguiente con fullcalendar: 
[image: este lo encontre con jquery aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/toytd26b/3/]

pero al tratar de hacerlo con angular obtengo este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
 ngOnInit() {
     
        this.calendarOptions = {
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: false,
            timeFormat: 'H:mm',
            axisFormat: 'HH:mm',
            slotDuration: '24:00',
            titleFormat : 'ddd D MMM YYYY',
            columnFormat : 'ddd D/YY',
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            height: "auto",
            contentHeight: "auto",
            resources: [
                {
                    id: 'a',
                    fname: 'John',
                    lname: 'Smith'
                },
                {
                    id: 'b',
                    fname: 'Jerry',
                    lname: 'Garcia'
                }
            ],
            resourceGroupField: 'id',
            resourceLabelText: 'Technicians',
            groupByResource:true,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'agendaWeek'
            }
        };

    }
```

```html
<ng-fullcalendar #ucCalendar [options]="calendarOptions"></ng-fullcalendar>
```

Comment: hola, ¿tienes el código html completo?

Comment: hola, en el html solo tengo esto : <ng-fullcalendar #ucCalendar [options]="calendarOptions"></ng-fullcalendar>

Comment: ¿Nos puedes mostrar el package.json?